# PC turns on but no signal to monitor (when restart it works)

Tags: windows-10, display, reboot

Windows 10 64bit 19042.906
Monitor AOC 24E1Q
AMD Ryzen 3 1200
GeForce GTX 1050Ti 461.92
8GB RAM DDR4
Gigabyte 500W Bronze

When i turn on the PC on the monitor appears no signal. If i restart the PC the monitor gets signal and everything goes well. I checked the display port cable, monitor, memory stick ram, video card, power supply and all drivers and windows are updated to the latest version.
My question is why the monitor does not receive signal until after restart ?

Comment: MB AsRock A320M-DVS R3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things, one of which would be a specific driver version or bios

Test video card driver with an older version or disable secure boot mode

Comment: i changed the video driver with an older version and i had no problems. Then i installed the last driver again (i deleted the profile) and no need to restart. Thanks